# C++ assigning to an array from an initializer list

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I have been working on a program to display a menu to the screen.
It was working but

```
void parser() {
    parsed[0]=data[position];
    for (i=1; i<=Choices; i++) {
        for (ii = 0; ii<= Depth-cDepth; ii++) {
            incriment += pow(Choices, ii);
        }
        incriment++;
        buff = position + incriment;
        parsed[i] = data[buff];
    }
    cout << parsed;
}
```

is returning the error:

```
- invalid types ‘std::string [3] {aka std::basic_string<char> [3]}[double]’ for array subscript
```

Any help would be appreciated, and I know there are similar questions but I couldn't understand the answers.

- EDIT: The error is on the line parsed[i]=data[buff]
- EDIT 2: I added icopy = i, where  icopy is an int and it compiles, although now durring runtime I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Comment: What are the types of `buff` and `data`?

Comment: data is a string list and buff is an intiger

Comment: It would help to know which line has the error. The only places where you are using an array subscript are `parsed[0]=data[position]` and `parsed[i] = data[buff]`. That would seem to indicate that either `position`, `i`, or `buff` are not actually integer types. Please post the declaration of those variables.

Comment: What's `parsed`? What's `i`? Every declaration is important. Please, post all relevant declarations.

Comment: So please show us the declarations of `i` and `buff`. (From its name, `buff` doesn't sound like an integer. But we can't know unless you show us the declarations.)

Comment: Thankyou, i was a double.

Comment: `data` is a *list*??? How did you manage to use `[]` operator with a list?

Comment: buff is an intiger and parsed is an array of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, you are using a `double` value to subscript an array, which is illegal. That's all there is to it.

Which application of `[]` operator produces the error - only you know, since we cannot derive it from what you posted without seeing the declarations. Judging by the bits and pieces of information you supplied so far, the culprit must be the `parsed[i]` subexpression, where `i` appears to be a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's telling you that you ran off the end of data[]  e.g. data has 3 elements and your attempting to access the 4th remember it starts with 0 so data[3] is actually the 4th element.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell. Either i or buff is a double.

Just to make sure, try changing that line to:

```
parsed[int(i)] = data[int(buff)];
```

And see if it still happens.

Answer (score -1):

pow returns double,
incriment though may be an integer initially, it is converted to double, in the nested for loop.

Comment: Variables don't just change their type like that. If the variables were declared as integers, they will stay integers.

Comment: I was working on a project and I had some similar issues, that's why I thought maybe its the data type problem.

Comment: Voted down because a variable can't change type in C++.